# How to send timeseries data - generated by a bluetooth based sensor - to influxdb from a javascript client (chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, influxdb

I am working on a chrome extension that connects to a BLE based sensor that sends back data to the extension every second. I have to save this data to Influxdb (or any time series DB for that matter).

Following are the approaches that I could think of:

1. Batch the data for every 1 min and then make a rest API (written in nodejs) call with timestamps and data, from the nodejs server write data to influxdb by executing a create query.
2. Use an MQTT based javascript client which writes to a topic every second, execute the create query from the subscriber
3. thought of doing the same using kafka but could not find any js library to do the same.
4. bypass the server, directly write queries from client-side to influxdb.

Any thoughts around this requirement will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question can only lead to opinion based answers, as such is off topic.

Comment: I believe it's more of an architecture question than an opinion If someone who has worked in these kinds of scenarios throws some light it would be of great help to me.

Comment: I doubt (4) is possible, at least for the moment. (2) looks like the most realistic one. But since you will have to use MQTT over WebSocket - why not simply using WebSocket only? Or consider gRPC ...

Comment: "Any thoughts around this" is asking to start a discussion, not provide a single correct answer, which is not how a Q&A site like Stack Overflow works. Also which of the 4 proposed approaches is best is an opinion, because we don't know enough about to whole system to give a definitive answer.